# How can I view two files side by side in Notepad++ by creating c# plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins, notepad++

I know that Notepad++ have feature for view two codes side by side but my problem is that I don't know how I can create a plugin in C# for showing one window on the right side and 1 window in the left side.

I couldn't find any example in C# also. Would you mind help me in how I can find a related document about it? if you have a piece of code which can help me please share.

*I know how to write a plugin in c# for notepad++.

Comment: A quick survey of http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Development#What_should_a_plugin_do.3F gives me the impression that you have to send window messages in order to do what you want. So look at what you have to do in the editor's user interface to create two edit windows and place them side by side and send the respective commands from inside your plugin. That should be relatively language independent. However it's just a guess.

Comment: @oliver:I found a cpp example for compare file but i was thinking of a c# example

Comment: Well, I don't think that it is too complicated to translate the example to c#. Presumably the API is the same. And c++ and c# are not all that different.